# How to show something to users, only when they are logged in

Tags: python, html, inheritance, flask, conditional-statements

so I'm making this website and I'm trying to figure out, how to show something on the navbar, if the user is logged in. I use inheritance, so I have my navbar in my layout.html. I'm not sure how to put the condition in there, so that it would work with all of my code, on every page. I was thinking that I could put in an if statement and then define it in every route, but I have about 20 routes and I'm trying to find more effective solution. I'm coding in python, using Flask. Thanks everyone for their help.

Edit: I forgot to add code

Here is my login function

```
@app.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    if request.method == "POST":
        name=request.form.get("name")
        password = request.form.get("password")
        sqlname = db.execute(text("SELECT name FROM users WHERE name=:name"),{"name":name}).fetchone()
        sqlpassword = db.execute(text("SELECT password FROM users WHERE name=:name"),{"name":name}).fetchone()
        if sqlname == None:
            message="You are not registered with this username, please register first."
            return render_template("registration.html", message=message)
        else:
            for passw in sqlpassword:
                if passw == password:
                    session["name"] = name
                    return redirect(url_for("dashboard"))
                else:
                    message = "Something went wrong, please try again."
                    return render_template("login.html", message=message)
    elif "name" in session:
            return redirect(url_for("dashboard"))
    return render_template("login.html")
```

Here is my layout.html, I just want to hide the form, if user isn't logged in

```
  <nav>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" action="{{ url_for('search')}}">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" name="search" placeholder="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using flask-login or flask-user, it is possible to add an if statement to the main template (layout.html?)in your navbar. Also see https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

```
{% if current_user.is_authenticated %}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, unfortunately I'm using just sessions.

Comment: It would help if you show some code to help us understand what kind of login mechanism you are using.

Comment: I didn't realize, I put it there now

Comment: You can pass session["name"] to your render template and add an {% if session %} in the template. You would also need some kind of code to prevent user from directly opening the dashboard without session. Have you thought of that? As you already have a sql database,it isn't much work to implement flask login.